# Convert unsigned char* to const char* - Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, char

I'm trying to convert on **unsigned char*** to one **const char*** and I know that exists `reinterpret_cast<const char*>` but I can't use that on **android**, always print garbage.

Can you please suggest me another way of doing this?

Comment: Are you sure the `reinterpret_cast` causes the garbage, and not that it was already garbage?

Comment: What kind of data do you have and how is "printed". A `const char*` might be considered a C style string by the I/O.

Comment: I would copy it as the source is `const`.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do?  Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And also [read about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @JamesRoot you are correct the only thing that I don't question, seems that I'm starting now to code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly type cast (in C- style) it to desired type.

For example

```
unsigned char* ptr_unsigned = new unsigned char[10];

const char* ptr_const = (const char*) ptr_unsigned;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: C-style casts are just unclear function-style casts. I think that's going to call reinterpret cast anyway.